# Get path for image from gallery Android

Tags: java, android, gallery, onactivityresult

Hi im trying to get  the path for an image from the gallery into a string but not having much luck I have tried numerous solutions but most of them are for getting an image from the gallery and and putting it on an Image View. Here is my code.. Any Suggestions. Thanks.

I am getting -1 for the result code and no output on the log.v

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Choose Image Source");
            builder.setItems(new CharSequence[] {"Gallery", "Camera"}, 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                    case 0:

                        // GET IMAGE FROM THE GALLERY
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        intent.setType("image/*");

                        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a Picture");

                        startActivityForResult(chooser, ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY);

                        break;

                    case 1:
                        Intent getCameraImage = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

                        File cameraFolder;

                        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals
                                (android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                            cameraFolder = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"zwave/");
                        else
                            cameraFolder= getActivity().getCacheDir();
                        if(!cameraFolder.exists())
                            cameraFolder.mkdirs();

                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
                        String timeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                        String imageFileName = "picture_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";

                        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
                                "zwave/" + imageFileName);
                        getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
                        Uri initialURI = Uri.fromFile(photo);


                        startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA);

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });

            builder.show();

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   Log.v("NAS",String.valueOf(resultCode));
    if (resultCode == 200)    {

        switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY:
             Uri mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
             Log.v("NAS",String.valueOf(mImageCaptureUri));
            break;

        case ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA:

            break;          
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: when `resultCode == -1` it means the operation succeeded! Change `resultCode == 200` -> `resultCode == RESULT_OK`  [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.. I changed that but it didn't work.. I removed the if statement but now I get a result back as a string but the path shows as /external/images/media/3609 not the proper path

Comment: Thats because it's a URI not path, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework/20559175#20559175) :)