# How to get Absolute path from android directory URI

Tags: android, audio, uri, filenotfoundexception

I got a audio file uri in `onActivityResult` but when i get a file from this URI it shows file not found exception and /directory/xxxx is not a absolute path.

Here is URI code : `Uri muri=data.getData();`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After Long Time Finally I Got Solution For this. i collected from [Get real path from URI, Android KitKat new storage access framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework/20559175#20559175) this link @Paul Burke Answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement that a `Uri` returned in `onActivityResult()` be a file that you can access directly. [A `Uri` is not necessarily a `File`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html).

Please use `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` on the data represented by the `Uri`.

Comment: i need to post a Audio File to server. how to use openInputStrem() please post some code

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.setType("audio/*");
            startActivityForResult(i, GET_MP3);

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == GET_MP3) {
Uri selectedmp3 = data.getData();
                mp3_path = getpathmp3(selectedmp3);
}

private String getpathring(Uri path) {
        String result;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                .query(path, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            result = path.getPath();
            int name = result.lastIndexOf("/");
            mp3_name = result.substring(name + 1);
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

            result = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
            int name = result.lastIndexOf("/");
            mp3_name = result.substring(name + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The mp3_path is the path you will get..tell me after trying this..

Comment: it showing cursor error - “make sure cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it…”

Comment: you can do it on your own, I have just mentioned a way to solve your problem, did it work or not??