# How to convert file URI to file path?

Tags: android, uri

I getting an URI when try to pick a file :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("file/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent,FILE_MANAGER_REQUEST_CODE);
```

In ActivityOnResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("FilePick", "request code = " + requestCode + ", resultCode = " + resultCode);
    Log.d("FilePick", "Intent = " + data != null ? data.getData().getPath() : null);

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

When i pick a file **data.getData().getPath()** returns

> **/external/file/15499**

How i convert it to real file path?

Note: I read this topics :

- [Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)
- [Get real path from URI, Android KitKat new storage access framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework)

But i think it's accessible onl;y for media content. Not for files.

Comment: `String path = yourURI.getPath();`

Answer (score 1):

There is no "real file path". [A `Uri` is not a `File`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html).

Please use `ContentResolver` and methods like `openInputStream()` to consume the content.

Comment: I want just a file path,not a content.

Comment: @SergeyShustikov: Your statement is akin to saying that you "want just a file path" for an HTTP URL. Talented programmers know that you do not have direct file access to a Web server, but instead need to open an `InputStream` and download a file pointed to by that URL. `Uri` values are much the same. There is no requirement for any `ContentProvider` to give you a `Uri` that points to a file, let alone a file that you can access, let alone with some deterministic conversion between the `Uri` and a local file path that you can access.