# Create new file in the directory returned by Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: java, android

In my App the user can choose a directory where to create an Excel file using the implicit intent ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.
However, the Uri returned in `onActivityResult()` cannot be used by `FileOutputStream()`. It throws a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/home%3A:test.xlsx (No such file or directory)
```

In `onActivityResult()` I check if the path exists via `File.exists()` and if not, I want to create a new Excel file.

**onActivityResult():**

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: called");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: path = " + data.getData()
                                                         .getPath());
            Uri treePath = data.getData();
            File path = new File(treePath + File.pathSeparator + "test.xlsx");
            if (path.exists()) {
                updateExistingExcelFile(path);
            } else {
                createNewExcelFile(path);
            }
        }
    }
```

**createNewExcelFile():**

```
    private void createNewExcelFile(File path) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createNewExcelFile: called");
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Cell cell;
        Sheet sheet;
        sheet = workbook.createSheet("Name of sheet");
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("Name");
        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("Number");
        sheet.setColumnWidth(0, (10 * 200));
        sheet.setColumnWidth(1, (10 * 200));
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
            workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                 .show();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "createNewExcelFile: ", e);
        }
    }
```

The code works perfectly fine if I use `Activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)` or something similar instead of the implicit intents path.

Comment: Don't try and convert the URI to a real path see https://stackoverflow.com/q/26972539/2373819

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Step #1: Take the `Uri` that you get from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and [pass it to `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile?hl=en#fromTreeUri(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)).

Step #2: Call [`createFile()` on that `DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile?hl=en#createFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to get a `DocumentFile` representing the child document.

Step #3: Call [`getUri()` on the `DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile?hl=en#getUri()) that you created in Step #2.

Step #4: Call [`openOutputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver?hl=en#openOutputStream(android.net.Uri)), passing in the `Uri` from Step #3, to get an `OutputStream` that you can use to write content. You get a `ContentResolver` by calling `getContentResolver()` on some `Context`, such as an `Activity`.

See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/11/09/scoped-storage-stories-trees.html) for more on using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Comment: Thanks, the file is now created. However I am getting a ``SecurityException`` ``java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10207 and Uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/home:/document/home:test.xlsx [user 0]``.
In ``onActivityResult()`` I am calling ``takePersistableUriPermission()`` on ``getContentResolver()`` like so: ``getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);`` and then I call ``createNewExcelFile(uri);``.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the call to ``takePersistableUriPersmission()`` and now it works perfectly fine. Thank you for your help.