# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() deprecated. So how to access custom folders in internal storage in android API 29?

Tags: android

As of API 29 `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated.

Earlier files were stored in a custom folder with path : `/storage/emulated/0/customFolder`

What I want is to save all files related to my app in this custom folder.

Is it advisable to use this way :

```
      val dir = File("/storage/emulated/0/customFolder")
```

Or can I use like this :

```
    val listDir = getExternalFilesDirs(null)
    val a =  listDir[0].toString()
    val p = a.splitToSequence("/")
    val h = "${p.elementAt(0)}/${p.elementAt(1)}/${p.elementAt(2)}/${p.elementAt(3)}"
    println(h) // this would return -  /storage/emulated/0
    val customFolder = File("$h/customFolder")
```

I have read about methods like `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getFilesDir()`, but using these won't satisfy my need as "files will be deleted when the application is uninstalled".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As of API 29 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated.

More importantly, [it does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58379543/115145). You cannot write to arbitrary locations on external storage on Android 10 and higher using filesystem APIs.

> What I want is to save all files related to my app in this custom folder

That will not be possible, sorry.

What you *can* do is [use the Storage Access Framework's `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61120265/115145) to allow the *user* to choose where on the *user's* device you should be storing the *user's* content.

> Is it advisable to use this way :

No, because you cannot write to that location.

> Or can I use like this :

No, because you cannot write to that location.

*Temporarily*, you can use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to disable the "scoped storage" change in Android 10 and allow your app to continue using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. That will stop working on Android 10 devices as soon as your `targetSdkVersion` hits 29, which you will need to do later this year to ship your app on the Play Store and certain other distribution channels.

Answer (score 0):

Scoped storage wont allow you to access files via `java.io.File`, unless `android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is granted. To enable you access custom folders without this permission, you can use [SimpleStorage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage):

```kotlin
// => /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder
val fileFromExternalStorage = DocumentFileCompat.fromSimplePath(context, basePath = "MyFolder")

// => /storage/9016-4EF8/MyFolder
val fileFromSdCard = DocumentFileCompat.fromSimplePath(context, storageId = "9016-4EF8", basePath = "MyFolder")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested on :

1. **Xiaomi M2102J20SI**
2. **Emulator Pixel 4 XL API 30**

Function `askPermission()` opens the target directory.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private fun askPermission() {
    val storageManager = application.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
    val intent =  storageManager.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()

    val targetDirectory = "WhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses" // add your directory to be selected by the user
    var uri = intent.getParcelableExtra<Uri>("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI") as Uri
    var scheme = uri.toString()
    scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/document/")
    scheme += "%3A$targetDirectory"
    uri = Uri.parse(scheme)
    intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri)
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

Uri of the file will be returned in `onActivityResult()`

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (data != null) {
                data.data?.let { treeUri ->

                    // treeUri is the Uri of the file
                    
                   // if life long access is required the takePersistableUriPermission() is used

                    contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                            treeUri,
                            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
                                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                    )

                  readSDK30(treeUri)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Function `readSDK30()` is used to read files & folders from `Uri`

```
  private fun readSDK30(treeUri: Uri) {
        val tree = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri)!!

        thread {
            val uriList  = arrayListOf<Uri>()
            listFiles(tree).forEach { uri ->
                 
                // Collect all the Uri from here
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Function `listFiles()` returns all the files & folders in the given `Uri`

```
fun listFiles(folder: DocumentFile): List<Uri> {
            return if (folder.isDirectory) {
                folder.listFiles().mapNotNull { file ->
                    if (file.name != null) file.uri else null
                }
            } else {
                emptyList()
            }
        }
```