# How to pick image or video on Android L?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using below code and it works fine below `android 5`. I am able to pick image or video from SD card.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("video/* image/*");
getActivity().startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

However on `Android L` it shows only videos. 
tried searching but didn't find anything, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hi @Mohit you can use this solution for image and video

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
photoPickerIntent.setType("*/*");
getActivity().startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

for both image and video you can use `setType(*/*);`

here **ACTION_GET_CONTENT** is give only gallery selection while **ACTION_PICK** give many more options to pick image and video from different action, So as per @DipeshDhakal answer you should use only **ACTION_GET_CONTENT**.

and this is work on android L and api 10 also.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
photoPickerIntent.setType("video/*, images/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Was running into a similar issue. Code that worked on 5.0 and below started breaking on 5.1+, and only filtered by the first type passed in.

A co-worker came up the following, and I thought I'd share:

We were previously using the following intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
i.setType("image/*,video/*");
```

and the following code to get the path from whatever the user selected, if anything:

```
public static String getFilePathFromURI(Uri imageUri, Activity context) {
    String filePath = null;

    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(imageUri,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return filePath;
}
```

Now:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.setType("*/*");

String[] mimetypes = {"image/*", "video/*"};
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
```

And to get the path, the getPath function found in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559175/434400