# No apps can perform this action

Tags: android, action, gallery, android-implicit-intent

When I am trying to invoke implicit intent with action **`"Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT"`**, I am getting this error alert **`"No apps can perform this action."`** Thanks in advance. Please see my code below.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("*/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
```

Comment: show code please.

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya Already added code. Please check it.

Answer (score 3):

Problem coming from **[setType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType(java.lang.String))** section .

> This is used to create intents that only specify a type and not data,
>   for example to indicate the type of data to return.

**Don't**

```
intent.setType("*/*"); // Arise problem
```

**Do**

```
 intent.setType("image/*");
```

**EDITED**

You can try with

```
Intent intent_open = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent_open.setType("image/* video/*");
```

Comment: I don't just want to open images, also I want videos.

Comment: I don't want to use ACTION_PICK, I want to use ACTION_GET_CONTENT. Please help me to this

Comment: @Drv https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380013/how-to-pick-image-or-video-on-android-l

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType("video/*, images/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an explicit MIME data type to intent. For example

```
  Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*"); //for image pick from gallery via intent
    intent.setType("video/*"); //for video pick from gallery via intent
```