# data.getData() sometimes returns null

Tags: java, android

I'm selecting a video file from the Gallery, but in some cases `data.getData()` returns null.

I open the Gallery by calling the following:

```
Intent intent;
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
} else {
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
}

intent.setType("video/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST);
```

Then in `onActivityResult` I first check if `data.getData()` is null or not, if it is I display a `Toast` message:

```
if (data.getData() != null) {
    //Do stuff
}else{
    //Display Toast
}
```

I've implemented the above after seeing [this blog post](http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-select-video-from-gallery-in-Android/6704/).

Some users reached out to me saying that they get the `Toast` message a lot.

Can someone please tell me why `data.getData` returns null when selecting a video file from `MediaStore`?

---

**Edit 1:**

After doing more research, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17765424/11951642). So I changed my `startActivityForResult` Intent to the following:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(new Intent().
    setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).
    setType("video/mp4"), "Select Video"),
    SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST);
```

I'm still not sure if this will resolve my issue because according to that answer `"The protocol for ACTION_PICK requires you to supply a Uri indicating the collection you are picking from"` I'm doing it correctly. I first check if a SD Card is mounted and change the Uri accordingly `android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6486827/11951642) also implies the following `"you will find support of ACTION_PICK spotty and inconsistent"`

I would really appreciate it if someone can provide me with an informative answer why my implementation failed in some cases and if the new implementation will resolve the issue I had?

Comment: Please refer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380013/how-to-pick-image-or-video-on-android-l/31740241)

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Please look at the link you have provided and then look at my implementation - `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`

Answer (score 0):

try this code it works fine on my device

```
 Intent videopicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            videopicker.setType("*/*");
            videopicker.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES,"video/*");
            startActivityForResult(videopicker, VIDEOPICK);
```

**onActivityResult**

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == VIDEOPICK) {
               Uri selectedvideo = data.getData();
               String videopath = selectedvideo.getPath();
                File file = new File(videopath);
                Log.e("path",file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Then If your android version is 7.0 and above you need to setup fileprovider.xml have you used it in your implementation?

Comment: File provider should be used when you want to share a file from your application with another application (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) I'm selecting a file, I do not have to use a file provider.