# Android TV app.Allow user select a video from storage(gallery,SD/USB) and get full path of file Intent ACTION_GET_CONTENT not working on TV

Tags: android, television

I am building TV app that lets user pick a video from storage and returns its full path. Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT not working on Android TV. But works on phone. TV not supporting Storage Access Framework.
MY CODE is not working on Android TV. Let me know how to achieve this.

```
fileintent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
fileintent.setType("video/*");
startActivityForResult(fileintent, 10 );
```

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                videopath = data.getDataString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, videopath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                videov.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videopath));
                videov.seekTo(1);
                //  videov.start();
            }

            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: You should check what information is printed in logcat console

Comment: --------- beginning of crash
2020-02-19 12:53:16.495 2576-2576/com.tv.hellotv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tv.hellotv, PID: 2576
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT typ=video/* }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1809)

Comment: Have you tried approach written out below in this issue? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380013/how-to-pick-image-or-video-on-android-l