# App crashes when picking image from external storage on android 5.1.1

Tags: android

In my App the user can pick an image from the gallery:

```
private void pickPicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    this.startActivityForResult(intent, Globals.REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO);
}
```

With the above code my gallery gets opened up and it shows me all my fotos but it is definetely not the old gallery i had on my phone (im using google nexus 4 with the newest android version 5.1.1). the new gallery looks like the following:

[image]

However when i now click on an image the app crashes:

```
07-29 18:30:41.896    2693-2693/de.mypackage.myproject E/CursorWindow﹕ Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 7 columns.
07-29 18:30:41.896    2693-2693/de.mypackage.myproject D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-29 18:30:41.898    2693-2693/de.mypackage.myproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.mypackage.myproject, PID: 2693
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/content://media/external/images/media/10961/ACTUAL/102077033 flg=0x1 (has clip) }} to activity {de.mypackage.myproject/de.mypackage.ProfileEditPictureActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3574)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
            at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
            at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
            at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
            at de.mypackage.utils.Helper.getRealPathFromURI(Helper.java:1064)
            at de.mypackage.fragments.profile.picture.ProfilePictureEditFragment.onActivityResult(ProfilePictureEditFragment.java:109)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:165)
            at de.mypackage.activities.ProfileEditPictureActivity.onActivityResult(ProfileEditPictureActivity.java:51)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

My `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == Globals.REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
            this.startCropImage();
        } else if (requestCode == Globals.REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO) {
            this.imageFile = new File(Helper.getRealPathFromURI(this.getActivity(), data.getData()));

            this.startCropImage();
        } else if (requestCode == Globals.REQUEST_CROP_PHOTO) {
            this.imageView.setImageBitmap(Images.loadBitmapFromFile(Paths.IMAGE_PROFILE));

            String message = this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_profile_save_completed);

            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And now the code where the app crashes:

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentURI) {
    String result = null;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else { 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 

        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 

        result = cursor.getString(index);
        cursor.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

The app crashes exactly at:

```
result = cursor.getString(index)
```

The code i posted above works on all android versions older than 5.1.1 but not on 5.1.1 so there need to be something different. Do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The code i posted above works on all android versions older than 5.1.1

Only on the couple of devices that you tried, and only for the photos that you tried.

[A `Uri` is not a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). You cannot get a "real path" for images, because there is no requirement that the `Uri` point to a file that you can access. For example, your code will not work for >400 million devices (all that shipped with Android 4.4+) for photos that are on removable media, because you do not have read access to arbitrary locations on removable media.

Use the `Uri` with a `ContentResolver` to get at the bytes represented by that `Uri` and the MIME type, much as you would use something like `HttpUrlConnection` to get the bytes and MIME type for a URL.

Comment: So i guess the answer from Paul Bruke here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework will solve it.

Comment: @Mulgard: No. For example, your app will still be broken on >400 million devices (all that shipped with Android 4.4+) for photos that are on removable media, because you do not have read access to arbitrary locations on removable media. The way to "solve it" is to do what I wrote, and use `ContentResolver` to access the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: I thought this is it. I cant find any other solutions with ContentResolver in the web.

Comment: oh is it simple as that? `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` but that means i need to create a temp file for each image because im working with files only.

Comment: @Mulgard: Ideally, you fix the rest of your code to not work with "files only".

Comment: I guess you are right. I could use `BitmapFactory` to create a `Bitmap` from the `InputStream`. Let's get to work. thx.

Comment: @CommonsWare, i noticed you posted this similar answer as a comment on another question. Please provider a code sample for us that arnt well versed in android.(i checked the link to your website aswell)

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when there no such column that you are fetching.
To make sure just print out your cursor by this

```
System.out.println(DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(yourcursor));
```

and see if there is such column or not.

Answer (score 0):

try with this method, and see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework)

```
public String getImagePath(Uri uri){
   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
   document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":")+1);
   cursor.close();

   cursor = getContentResolver().query( 
   android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
   null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
   cursor.close();

   return path;
}
```