# Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT opens recent files which gives a bad URI

Tags: android, android-intent, android-cursor, android-contentresolver

I'm using `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` which opens recent files. Selecting items from the recent files gives a bad URI but selecting the same file from the file manager gives a right URI which can be handled by my code.

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String path;
    if ("content".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        path = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    } else {
        path = uri.getPath();
    }

    return path;
}
```

**Note:** The `uri.getPath()` output when I select a PDF from the recent files is `/document/...` but selecting the same file from the file manager is, `.../emulated/...`.

**Note:** the error while selecting the file from the recent files is

> Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was my code doesn't handle the new Layout Storage URIs of Android. If you face this problem too, please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559175/3749773) because the writer is wrote a fantastic method to get real path of every URIs.

Comment: Thanks a lot !. Your linked article helped me to solve the problem.