# Why downloaded path is different from initial path on Android M using DownloadManager?

Tags: android, android-download-manager, download-manager, android-6.0-marshmallow

The code below works fine for Android < 6.0

Downloading:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
// Remove all whitespace and more char.
String fileName = pPackageBean.getSaveAsName().replaceAll("\\s+", "_").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-]", "");
request.setDescription(mContext.getString(R.string.application_name));
request.setTitle(pPackageBean.getSaveAsName());
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
id = mDownloadManager.enqueue(request);
pPackageBean.setDownloadId(id);
```

Handling success:

```
case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
long id = packageBean.getDownloadId();
Uri uri =  mDownloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(id);
packageBean.path = uri.getEncodedPath();
```

As result the uri is: `content://downloads/my_downloads/867` which is not expected.`867` is the download's id and don't know where `my_downloads` come from.

On 4.2.2 i get : `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Yvan_Test`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework/20559175#20559175

Comment: And what is your initial path? `String fileName = pPackageBean.getSaveAsName().replaceAll("\\s+", "_").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-]", "");
`. And what is the value of `fileName?

Comment: `don't know where my_downloads come from`. Then you should read a little about content providers. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html

Comment: `fileName` is not a path just a name.

Comment: i resolve the issue by using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework/20559175#20559175