# Image won't upload to FTP

Tags: java, android, ftp

So my program is selecting an image from the phone and then I want to upload it to an ftp that I have. I know the FTP connection works and I can succesfully upload a document by going to the file manager. My problem is when I select an image from my phone it detects the address as:

```
/external/images/media/34
```

but when I am uploading it the logcat says file doesn't exist:

```
03-09 16:00:32.702  19649-19678/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/34: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-09 16:00:32.706  19649-19678/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
03-09 16:00:32.706  19649-19678/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
03-09 16:00:32.706  19649-19678/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at net.azurewebsites.cosy.AddBook$UploadBook.doInBackground(AddBook.java:460)
03-09 16:00:32.706  19649-19678/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at net.azurewebsites.cosy.AddBook$UploadBook.doInBackground(AddBook.java:431)
03-09 16:00:32.706  19649-19678/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-09 16:00:32.706  19649-19678/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

It's obvious it's something to do with the filepath. 
Anybody know how to fix it so it selects the file and picks up a proper address
Here is my code for picking the file:

```
Intent galleryInent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(galleryInent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null)
    {
        selectedImage = data.getData();
        imageToUpload.setImageURI(selectedImage);

    }
```

and here is where I upload it to the ftp:

```
if (con.login("cosy\\username", "pass"))
{
    Log.v("connection:","Successful");
    con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
    con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    String data = file;

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
    if(type=="image")
    {
        con.changeWorkingDirectory("site/wwwroot/images/");
        result = con.storeFile(BookName + ".jpg", in);
    }
    if(type=="file")
    {
        con.changeWorkingDirectory("site/wwwroot/Books/");
        result = con.storeFile(BookName + ".pdf", in);
    }
    else
    {
        result =false;
    }
    in.close();
    if (result)
        Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
    con.logout();
    con.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The path your providing is not absolute that's why the file cannot be found. Try to use `getContentResolver` as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559175/1269953) keep in mind this is for all types of files. It's very in-depth answer, keep in mind the `SDK` checks what version the device is running so if you're targeting lower versions make sure you don't forget the code.