# How to get pdf,txt,doc,file path in android version grater than lollipop?

Tags: android, file, pdf

i want to get the path of file like pdf, txt, etc. so I used this "[how to get the file path of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109507/how-to-get-the-file-path-of-a-file)" code
from StackOverflow but this code is working with API level-22 and below but my project need is API-26.

Comment: you need to add run time permission for that beacuse **Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.** [read more from docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no path, because there is no file. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not have much to do with files.

If you absolutely need a file and absolutely need a path, do not use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. Instead, [use a library and embed a file picker in your app](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created).