# android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory), the file exists in the path with the name

Tags: android, android-studio, file, kotlin, apollo-android

I am trying to send an image to my apollo-graphql server, but I get the following error:

> android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

This is the Android code:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
                    val response = try {
                        apolloClient(requireContext()).mutate(
                            SubirImagenMutation(
                                imagenData = FileUpload("image/jpg", File(imagen.path!!).toString())
                            )
                        ).toDeferred().await()
                    } catch (e: ApolloException) {
                        Toasts().visualizarToast(requireContext(), getString(R.string.str_err_generico))
                        return@launch
                    }
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.serviciosFragment)
                }
```

The image path:

> /document/1804-2E16:DCIM/definicion-de-persona-min.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

App permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is not in this code ... the real problem is that you are using wrong code to get path from uri... as the only good way is: ***to create new file and copy content from uri to this file and use its path*** (or use content directly) ... similar questions are asked again and again because some dudes give +1 for wrong answers

Answer (score 0):

not every `URI` can be resolved as strict file path on file system. e.g. some file pickers can return file placed on some cloud storage...

in your case `URI` points on `/document/1804-2E16:DCIM/definicion-de-persona-min.jpg`, which is malformed for shure. you are probably getting `URI` similar to this `/document/1804-2E16` thinking that this is directory path, so you are adding `String` filename, but this isn't how this works... your real original and full "path" to file looks probably like this:

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1804-2E16
```

no filename, no fileformat, just a "pointer" - an `URI`

read about [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider)s and check out [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109507/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-a-uri-that-points-to-a-pdf-document) topic for some info how to obtain access to such files. fixing this "bug" isn't trivial, in short you have to handle some file streams

Comment: Manually testing the path, I get the same error: File("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/1804-2E16:DCIM/definicion-de-persona-min.jpg")

Comment: this is NOT a file path! this is `URI` pointing on a file, which may be stored anywhere, so it can be converted only to a stream. `File` object may be created only from `URI` starting with `file://`. and no, manually replacing `content://` to `file://` won't fix this. seems like you haven't read my answer at all and for shure didn't read linked doc and topic on SO...