# File not found exception (Path from URI)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, fileinputstream

I'm trying to get a `FileInputStream` object for the picture a user selects from their gallery and when I'm trying to open the file from the URI I receive, it keeps saying `FileNotFoundException`...

Here's the code I'm using to fire off the intent for picking an image from the gallery:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

And here's the code I use for catching `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        File myFile = new File(uri.getPath());
        FileInputStream fiStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        ...
    }

}
```

Right on the creation of the `FileInputStream`, I get the folloiwng error upon choosing one of my photos via the emulator:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:26171: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Maybe I'm retrieving the file from the URI incorrectly??? Any help here would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

### Solution

I ended up using https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2725
It's very easy to use!

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> i think you just forgot to add this

Comment: @KeyurLakhani I added that to my manifest and same error :/

Comment: put Log onactivityresult and check uri.getPath() is it null ??

Comment: tried `ContentResolver#openInputStream`?

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same issue.

**My problem**
I was using this code

```
        @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
```

until when I found out it could not handle a bigger image.
I had to change and use another method to get the image.

Using InputStream

```
            File file= new File(uri.getPath());
            FileInputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(file);
```

This gives a file not found exception for the path format is the reason

As Knossos said

> "The Uri that you are attempting to open is
>   content://document/image:26171. You need to access it with a
>   ContentProvider

Thanks to Paul Burke with his library aFileChooser http://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser

To make it simple just create a class I called it **FileChooser.java**

```
        import android.content.ContentUris;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Build;
        import android.os.Environment;
        import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
        import android.provider.MediaStore;


        public class FileChooser {

            /**
             * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
             * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
             * other file-based ContentProviders.
             *
             * @param context The context.
             * @param uri The Uri to query.
             * @author paulburke
             */
            public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

                final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

                // DocumentProvider
                if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
                    // ExternalStorageProvider
                    if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                        final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                        final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                        final String type = split[0];

                        if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                        }

                        // TODO handle non-primary volumes
                    }
                    // DownloadsProvider
                    else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                        final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                        final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                    }
                    // MediaProvider
                    else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                        final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                        final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                        final String type = split[0];

                        Uri contentUri = null;
                        if ("image".equals(type)) {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        }

                        final String selection = "_id=?";
                        final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                                split[1]
                        };

                        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
                    }
                }
                // MediaStore (and general)
                else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                    return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
                }
                // File
                else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                    return uri.getPath();
                }

                return null;
            }

            /**
             * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
             * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
             *
             * @param context The context.
             * @param uri The Uri to query.
             * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
             * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
             * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
             */
            public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                               String[] selectionArgs) {

                Cursor cursor = null;
                final String column = "_data";
                final String[] projection = {
                        column
                };

                try {
                    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                            null);
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                        return cursor.getString(column_index);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (cursor != null)
                        cursor.close();
                }
                return null;
            }


            /**
             * @param uri The Uri to check.
             * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
             */
            public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
                return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
            }

            /**
             * @param uri The Uri to check.
             * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
             */
            public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
                return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
            }

            /**
             * @param uri The Uri to check.
             * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
             */
            public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
                return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
            }
        }
```

Then we can simply access it in our activity result

```
        @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    try {
                        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(FileChooser.getPath(getContext(),uri));
```

As I wanted to resize the image before using it there is the full code... I hope it helps someone...;) Thanks to blubl

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            /*Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);*/

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(FileChooser.getPath(getContext(),uri));

            int dstWidth = 1980;
            int dstHeight = 960;
            int inWidth, inHeight;

            //get image size
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            in.close();

            inWidth = options.outWidth;
            inHeight = options.outHeight;

            in = new FileInputStream(FileChooser.getPath(getContext(),uri));
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            // decode full image pre resized
            options.inSampleSize = Math.max(inWidth/dstWidth, inHeight/dstHeight);

            Bitmap roughtBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);

            Matrix m = new Matrix();
            RectF inRect = new RectF(0, 0, roughtBitmap.getWidth(), roughtBitmap.getHeight());
            RectF outRectF = new RectF(0, 0, dstWidth, dstHeight);
            m.setRectToRect(inRect, outRectF, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
            float[] values = new float[9];
            m.getValues(values);

            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(roughtBitmap, (int)(roughtBitmap.getWidth() * values[0]), (int)(roughtBitmap.getHeight() * values[4]), true);

            currentQrItem.setPicture(resizedBitmap);
            adapter.changeImage(currentQrItem);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using the same method. It worked perfectly for me. but now it gives an error

" Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/Images/405435.jpg" "
at line 

 final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

My target sdk is 29
im using runtime permissions

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is that you are attempting to access a content Uri as though it were a File.

The Uri that you are attempting to open is `content://document/image:26171`. You need to access it with a `ContentProvider`.

An example to do so can be found with this great [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20413475/503508).

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
```

// in onactivity result

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
                CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,null);
                Cursor cursor =cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
                int scale = 1;
                while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                        && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    scale *= 2;
                options.inSampleSize = scale;
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
```

Comment: What I'm aiming for here is getting the file in a bytes array, so a FileInputStream would be more appropriate, but I will try it with your intent setup and see what happens. Do you know of a way to go from URI straight to File properly?

Comment: Why does this help? Code only answers aren't helpful to help the asker learn.

Comment: File myFile = new File(selectedImagePath); use this then add your code

Comment: yes!!! get bitmap first then convert into file or there are many solutions as per your requirement

Comment: Do you mind giving a brief rundown of whats going on here

Comment: I want in Bitmap so I am converting selected path to bitmap

Comment: This results in a blank image :/

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting 23 SDK version? If so, you must get runtime permission for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Clarification on post is best contained in the comments section

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the answer here:

[How to write a file using Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166061/how-to-write-a-file-using-intent-action-create-document)

Simply use **getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)** to create your input stream instead of a filePath.