# BitmapUtils throwing FileNotFoundException on foldername having space while getting bitmap from uri

Tags: android, android-bitmap, filenotfoundexception

Getting FileNotFoundException on folders **having space** on Android 5.1. Otherwise its working fine.
I tried replacing space with `%20` but din't work. Also tried URLEncoder but it's failing.

I'm getting path of image using contentresolver:

```
absolutePathOfImage=cursor.getString(column_index_data);
```

which is (/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20181025-WA0001.jpg)

Uri:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Images/IMG-20181024-WA0022.jpg
```

I want to get bitmap of image but while **getting bitmap from Uri**,  BitmapUtils throwing exception: (Note: even Glide,picasso is failing to create thumbnail of image)

```
        BitmapUtils.decodeSampledBitmap(mContext, mUri, mWidth, mHeight);
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load sampled bitmap: file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Images/IMG-20181024-WA0022.jpg
>   /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20181024-WA0022.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I'm getting exception on Android 5.1.
Same code working on Android 8.0

Stuck with it since 2 days. Any workaround or solution?

Comment: check this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43233922/6021469

Comment: Are you sure the issue is because of the spacing? Have you tried with a folder without space?
Also, make sure your application has read permission to external storage, both in manifest file and dynamically.

Comment: Yes. without space its working! App is in production!

Comment: have you tried using android.net.Uri.encode or URLEncoder.encode(yourUriPath, "UTF-8") ?

Comment: yes as mentioned in question tried both.

Answer (score 2):

the space should not be encoded, alike an URL:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Images/IMG-20181024-WA0022.jpg
```

but it should be escaped with `\`, alike a Linux path:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp\ Images/IMG-20181024-WA0022.jpg
```

also make sure that the base-path `file:///storage/emulated/0` is correct.