# gallery Image not display in image view

Tags: android, image, android-activity, android-gallery

Here is My two activity . I am trying to display the image in a image view of other activity . for camera its work fine But for gallery it is not display in image view. i.e. after selecting the image in imageview, it seems blank.I have seen many answer on SO But none of them work for me.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * @author aditya
 */
public class UploadFinding extends BaseActivity {


    // LogCat tag
    private static final String TAG = UploadFinding.class.getSimpleName();
    Bitmap b;

    public static final String IMAGE_URL = "imageURL";
    // Camera activity request codes
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 1337;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    String imgDecodableString;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;



    protected static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    Button capture_photo, capture_video;

    private Uri mFileUri;
    TextView textview1,textview2,textview3;

    private final Context mContext = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * Adding our layout to parent class frame layout.
         */
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.upload_finding_layout, frameLayout);



        //for Design
        textview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Typeface face1= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf");
        textview1.setTypeface(face1);

        textview2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Typeface face2= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf");
        textview2.setTypeface(face2);

        textview3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        Typeface face3= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf");
        textview3.setTypeface(face3);



        capture_photo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture_photo);
        capture_video = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture_video);


        capture_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UploadFinding.this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Capture");
                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("From Camera",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                mFileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(1);
                                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);
                                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
                            }

                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("From Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                mFileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(1);
                                i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);
                                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            }

        });


//End Btn_Click


        // For Camera

        capture_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UploadFinding.this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Capture");
                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("From Camera",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
//
                                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 5);


                                mFileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(2);

                                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);
                                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10);
                                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("From Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                 i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);
                                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }

        });

        /**
         * Setting title and itemChecked
         */
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(listArray[position]);

    }


    /**
     * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
     * app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", mFileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        mFileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }

//
//
    //multipart

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


                // successfully captured the image
                // launching upload activity
                launchUploadActivity(true);


            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // video successfully recorded
                // launching upload activity
                launchUploadActivity1(true);

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                // user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else {
                // failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }

        if(requestCode==RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                launchUploadActivity2(true);
            }
        }
//        {
    }


    private void launchUploadActivity(boolean isImage) {
        Intent i = new Intent(UploadFinding.this, Finding_Preview_Image.class);
        i.putExtra("filePath", mFileUri.getPath());
        i.putExtra("isImage", isImage);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private void launchUploadActivity1(boolean isImage) {
        Intent i = new Intent(UploadFinding.this, Finding_preview_video.class);
        i.putExtra("filePath", mFileUri.getPath());
        i.putExtra("isImage", isImage);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private void launchUploadActivity2(boolean isImage) {
        Intent i = new Intent(UploadFinding.this, Finding_Preview_Image.class);
        i.putExtra("filePath", mFileUri.getPath());
        i.putExtra("isImage", isImage);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    // Return image / video
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
//        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
//        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
//        return image;
        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        }

        else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;

    }
}
```

Next activity

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Finding_Preview_Image extends BaseActivity {

    private Button finding_upload_button;

    // private ImageView photo;
// multipart
// LogCat tag
    private static final String TAG = UploadFinding.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private String filePath = null;
    // private TextView txtPercentage;
    private ImageView photo;
    private EditText fullname;
    private VideoView vidPreview;
    private Button Finding_upload_button;
    long totalSize = 0;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.finding__preview_image, frameLayout);

        finding_upload_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finding_upload_button);
        photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.find_Image);
        fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.find_Image);
        //multipart
        // txtPercentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        // vidPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);


        // Receiving the data from previous activity
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // image or video path that is captured in previous activity
        filePath = i.getStringExtra("filePath");

        // boolean flag to identify the media type, image or video
        boolean isImage = i.getBooleanExtra("isImage", true);

        if (filePath != null) {
            // Displaying the image or video on the screen
            Log.i("UploadApp", "file path is null");
            previewMedia(isImage);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry, file path is missing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        finding_upload_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // uploading the file to server
                new UploadFileToServer().execute();
            }
        });


    }
//
    //Displaying captured image/video on the screen

    private void previewMedia(boolean isImage) {


        // Checking whether captured media is image or video
        if (isImage) {
            photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // vidPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();


            // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 88;


            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        //else {
//            photo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            vidPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            vidPreview.setVideoPath(filePath);
//            // start playing
//            vidPreview.start();
//        }
    }

    /**
     * Uploading the file to server
     * */
    private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // setting progress bar to zero
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // Making progress bar visible
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // updating progress bar value
            progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

            // updating percentage value
            //   txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return uploadFile();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private String uploadFile() {
            String responseString = null;

            try {

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);



                Log.i("UploadApp", "upload url: " + Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);


                AndroidMultiPartEntity entity;
                entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                        new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void transferred(long num) {
                                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                            }
                        });

                File sourceFile;
                sourceFile = new File(filePath);

                Log.i("UploadApp", "file path: " + filePath);

                // Adding file data to http body
                entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
                entity.addPart("fullname", new StringBody(fullname.getText().toString()));


                totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                // Making server call
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    // Server response
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                } else {
                    responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                            + statusCode;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
                Log.e("UploadApp", "exception: " + responseString);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
                Log.e("UploadApp", "exception: " + responseString);
            }

            return responseString;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

            // showing the server response in an alert dialog
            showAlert(result);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Method to show alert dialog
     * */
    private void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


}
```

Comment: Find answer of  "Paul Burke" in below stackoverflow link; this may solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework

Comment: Why? what is the problem with that?

Comment: Because I have no idea for ,how to put those functions in putExtra For transfer in other activity

Comment: place getPath() method in utility or some where
and call it in your launchUploadActivity() like 
String realPath=getPath(this, mFileUri)  how ever this method returns string.
And finaly, i.putExtra("filePath", realPath);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for Pic from gallery

Launch gallery intent and select image

```
 Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
 galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
 galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Then in on Activity result

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode==RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE){
                mFileUri=data.getData();
                launchUploadActivity2(true);
            }
        }
}
```

In launchUploadActivity2(true)

```
 String realPath=getPath(this, mFileUri) 
 i.putExtra("filePath", realPath);
```

Comment: Thanx Man ur solution on given link works..But this woking explicitly not like a modular function.Because calling getImage path not work in upload activity.. It is work on It is work on request code block.Have u any another suggestion to make it work on upload activity function

Comment: This answer have issue in getPath() funtion

Comment: What issue you are facing?