# Not able to copy pdf file from raw to run time created sdcard folder

Tags: android, writefile, file-storage

i use this code to  create a folder in sdcard n it is created sucesfully

```
private void CreateFolder() {
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
            File.separator + "Books");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdir();
    }
    if (success) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Books Folder Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        // Do something else on failure
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

}
```

And these lines of code to copy a file from res/raw to this folder but this cannot copy specified pdf file in that folder

```
 try{
                copyFile(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.the_reader)
                , new FileOutputStream(new File(context.getFilesDir(),"/sdcard/Books/the_reader.pdf")));
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



                File pdfFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "/sdcard/Books/the_reader.pdf");
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                startActivity(intent);
```

Copy file code

```
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
}
```

But no able to copy permissions are also added in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

It cannot copy pdf file in that specified folder ...

Comment: are you using marshmallow ?? android 6.0+??

Comment: Then you need to add permissions programmatically. See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37269354/6127411.

Comment: Have added code for take permission run time for android 6.0+

Answer (score 0):

some changes to you copyFile method:

```
public void copy(InpputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: do you have sd card? may be copy of file created but Intent to show pdf not work