# Share screenshot in android

Tags: android, share, screenshot

I don't have SD card in my mobile also was hoping people who use my app may or may not have it. Now when I tried to share my screenshot it works in few mobiles and does not work in few. In all these mobiles none of them have SD card. Also I want to make sure that the screenshots should not get saved anywhere so that it will not be visible in the gallery. I tried with the following methods:

- getExternalStorageState()
- getDatadirectory()
- getFilesDir()
- getDir()
- getCacheDir()

But I still couldn't get the right approach in doing so. This is the present code that I'm working on :

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);    
view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),    
View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
view.layout( view.getLeft(),  view.getTop(),  view.getLeft() + view.getMeasuredWidth(),  view.getTop() + view.getMeasuredHeight());
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
view.destroyDrawingCache();
view.invalidate();
view.refreshDrawableState();
File path = new File(getApplicationContext().getDir("Default", Context.MODE_ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING),"myapp");
File directory = new File(path.getAbsolutePath());
directory.mkdirs();
String filename = "myapp" + new Date() + ".png";
File yourFile = new File(directory, filename);
try
{
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(yourFile, true);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90,out);
out.flush();
out.close();
send(yourFile);
}catch (IOException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now my focus is on sharing the screenshot in a mobile where it does not have SD card and it should not save anywhere so that the screenshots wouldn't keep dumping as I go on sharing. How to do it ?

**EDIT** : 
Now I started working on getDir() method so that the files will be getting saved on Application data as noted by my friend Ashish Vora. I have found that the files are getting saved inside but it is not retrieved back for sharing. All I'm getting is a blank screen.

Comment: If you are using marshmallow refer to this answer.. [Marshmallow issues](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37269354/6127411)..!!

Comment: Followed that article and edited my code and it is asking permission at first but still getting a blank screen while sharing

Answer (score 1):

Best thing is to save it using getDir().
So it will be in your Application data and not visible in Gallery. Also you can share it using your Application.

So save it as:

```
File path = new File( getDir(YOUR_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY_NAME, Context.MODE_ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING));
File directory = new File(path.getAbsolutePath()+ "/my app");
```

Else you can use as:

```
File directory = new File(getDir("my app", Context.MODE_ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING));
```

Comment: what should I assign in my "YOUR_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY_NAME".

Comment: You can use directly also. But i prefer to Create a folder in data first then add anything into it. See updated answer.

Comment: The screenshot is not getting saved. I tried it with Lenova vibe with marshmallow update. Even the folder is not getting created.

Comment: Marshmallow has Permission issues. Have you checked Permission for your Application?

Comment: Yes i have included the following four permission in manifest file.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: See updated Answer and also set targetSdkVersion = 23.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116044/discussion-between-reaching-out-and-ashish-vora).