# Android ThumbnailUtils returning null, filenotfoundexception?

Tags: android, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

Currently attempting to get a thumbnail from a returned video (either from gallery or from the video intent on the device) to display in an ImageView, but am getting FileNotFound exceptions and a null Bitmap being returned. Not entirely sure where I'm going wrong although judging by the error it must be the path that is not right somehow. Any ideas?

```
if (requestCode == GALLERY_VIDEO_CODE  || requestCode == VIDEO_CODE) {
            videoURI = data.getData();
            if(videoURI != null) {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, videoURI);
                int duration = mp.getDuration();
                mp.release();
                if (duration <= 11000) {
                    addBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    clearBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Video added!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    File file = new File(videoURI.getPath());
                    Bitmap bm = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                    userPhoto.setImageBitmap(bm);
                } else {
                    videoURI = null;
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Video too long - maximum duration is 10 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    addBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    clearBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
```

Comment: `File file = new File(videoURI.getPath())` -- this only works if the `Uri` has a `file` scheme. Most of the time, you will not have a `Uri` with a `file` scheme. Instead, it will have a `content` scheme.

Comment: In which case, is there any way I can get a thumbnail for it?

Comment: Pass `videoURI` to Picasso and let it get you a thumbnail: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v7.6/RecyclerView/VideoList/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/recyclerview/videolist/RowController.java#L61-L65

Comment: Having issues again, doesn't seem to be loading anything into the imageview - have tried both videoURI and videoURI.toString as suggested   in the code you linked. Beginning to think I'm just cursed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat solved this by getting my filepath to put into the createVideoThumbnail() method using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20470572/5325511