# Open file from documents on Android Nougat

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm using file helper class from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559175/2281821 but it doesn't working properly in each case. I'm using `Intent chooseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);` to start file picker. I have Android Nougat and I'm receiving from onActivityResult uri: `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/home%3Aimage.png`
What does this `home:` means? How can I get access to this file? I was trying with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and `System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")` but I can't get acess.

Comment: Are u getting any error or exception than plz paste it here also

Comment: There is no error, the path is just incorrect and when I try to create bitmap, it is null

Answer (score 0):

Following code can be used to get document path:

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent .setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent , getString(R.string.app_name)),REQUEST_CODE);
```

OnActivityResult():

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
                Uri uri  = data.getData();
            } 
        }

    }
```

You can use "uri" variable value to get bitmap. If you want to open document other image also then remove following line:

```
galleryIntent .setType("image/*");
```

Answer (score 0):

You get access to a content scheme by opening for instance an InputStream on the uri.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

BitmapFactory.decodeFromStream(is) will happily read from your stream.

Comment: is there any way to get the Uri to locate the file?