# Convert content:// uri into a file path

Tags: android, filesystems

I am having problems converting a uri to a path because of the content tag. So I am trying to select any file type from the Android storage, and I am able to select a file but when I grab the data and try to convert it to a string path my app crashes.

My code to convert the uri looks like

```
String path = data.getData().getPath();
```

I've looked around and some say to use a Content provider and content resolver, but I'm not sure how to use them. Any help would be great thanks.

Display it/ upload it to an s3 bucket. When I mean display it, I mean if it's a photo, or video to show it and if it's an audio file I'd like to be able to play it and the same with other files, like PDF and so on.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the file? why do you need the path?

Comment: Display it/ upload it to an s3 bucket. When I mean display it, I mean if it's a photo, or video to show it and if it's an audio file I'd like to be able to play it and the same with other files, like PDF and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This method returns the `Path` as `String`

```
private String getPath(Uri uri) {

            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,null);

            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
```

Comment: Using the above code I am getting a runtime exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:206 flg=0x43 }}

Comment: MinSdk is 21 and TargetSdk is 26. The uri right now is for local storage, but I would like the option for both.

Comment: This is what the uri that is returned when I log it. content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:206

Comment: hard to relate, the above method works fine and tested. though, there's two type of data returned from ACTION_GET_CONTENT see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20067508/7569106) I tested on content://media/external/images/media/3303 not your type maybe that's the reason. but that also will not throw a RuntimeException. if you could edit your question for more code would be better