# Get File Extension on Samsung Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to get the File extension from a Chooser Intent on an Samsung Galaxy S5.

The first returns an empty string and for the second one i get an empty string aswell.

The uri I get from the Chooser intent is

> content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/12537

```
string test = MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.ToString()); // empty
string fName = uri.LastPathSegment.Split(new char[] { '\\', ':', '/' }).Last(); // Empty aswell
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Uri yourUrl; //your uri
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
    String mimeType = contentResolver.getType(yourUrl);
    MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(mimeType);
```

Comment: This still returns null.

Comment: Alright, I have another solution, I’ll edit my answer soon

Comment: mimeType is application/something, but this solves my problem somewhat but not completely. Thanks though in advance.

Comment: so when you you log the variable mimeType it logs application/"filetype"?

Comment: Yes but that is still not the Extension

Comment: do you mean that you want the full path? or extension as in .jpg or .png or etc

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer addresses part of the problem. For a complete solution (in the form of a library), look at Paul Burke'answer.
 [Get real path from URI, Android KitKat new storage access framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework/20559175#20559175)