# Android storage access framework persistable permission not granted during asyntask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, permissions, android-bitmap

I set the intent flags here:

```
public void createAlbum(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
    String intentChooserDialog = getResources().getString(R.string.pick_image_dialog);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, intentChooserDialog), PICK_IMAGE);
}
```

Here in my activity result I set the persistable permissions as they are explained [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        // Get image selection
        if (data != null) {
            ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
            if (clipData != null) {
                int clipDataCount = clipData.getItemCount();
                if (clipDataCount > 1) {
                    int clipIndex = 0;
                    BitmapUri[] bitmapUris = new BitmapUri[clipDataCount];
                    while (clipIndex < clipDataCount) {
                        ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(clipIndex);
                        Uri uri = item.getUri();
                        int takeFlags = data.getFlags();
                        takeFlags &= Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION;
                        getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
                        BitmapUri bitmapUri = new BitmapUri(Uri.decode(uri.toString()),            data.getFlags());
                        bitmapUris[clipIndex] = bitmapUri;
                        clipIndex++;
                    }
                    DatabaseAlbumWriter dab = new DatabaseAlbumWriter(this);
                    dab.execute(bitmapUris);
                }
            } else {
                int oneImageSelected = 1;
                BitmapUri[] bitmapUris = new BitmapUri[oneImageSelected];
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                int takeFlags = data.getFlags();
                takeFlags &= Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION;
                getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
                BitmapUri bitmapUri = new BitmapUri(Uri.decode(uri.toString()), data.getFlags());
                bitmapUris[0] = bitmapUri;
                DatabaseAlbumWriter dab = new DatabaseAlbumWriter(this);
                dab.execute(bitmapUris[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After the content style Uri’s are saved to a sqlite3 database, I want to load them in a gridview, but asynchronously as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html). Here is my implementation of decodeSampledBitmapFromResource from the training guide. An object with a decoded String of the Uri and the persistable permission from the original intent are passed in. These values were saved in the database and loaded here again.

```
        protected Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(BitmapUri bitmapUri, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(bitmapUri.getStringUri());
        int permissions = bitmapUri.getPermissions();
        permissions &= Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION;
        try {
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, permissions);
            ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Rect rect = new Rect(-1,-1,-1,-1);
            BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, rect, options);
            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, rect, options);
            parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        } catch (NullPointerException | SecurityException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

It is here that I get this error:

```
05-08 14:17:40.850 2728-2813/com.example.app W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10058 and Uri 0 @ content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:32
05-08 14:17:40.850 2728-2813/com.example.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
05-08 14:17:40.850 2728-2813/com.example.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
05-08 14:17:40.850 2728-2813/com.example.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.takePersistableUriPermission(ActivityManagerNative.java:4217)
05-08 14:17:40.850 2728-2813/com.example.app W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(ContentResolver.java:1703)
05-08 14:17:40.850 2728-2813/com.example.app W/System.err:     at com.example.app.AlbumCreator$BitmapWorkerTask.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(AlbumCreator.java:395)
05-08 14:17:40.850 2728-2813/com.example.app W/System.err:     at com.example.app.AlbumCreator$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(AlbumCreator.java:343)
05-08 14:17:40.850 2728-2813/com.example.app W/System.err:     at com.example.app.AlbumCreator$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(AlbumCreator.java:329)
```

If I load the bitmap from a parcelFileDescriptor with BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor in the activity result I do not get this error. So, from what I can tell, the AsyncTask is a different user with different privileges. Anyone know how to assign persistable permissions to an AsyncTask? I’d rather not load bitmaps on the UI thread.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".AlbumCreator"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AlbumEditor"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_album_editor"
            android:parentActivityName=".AlbumCreator">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.app.AlbumCreator" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414352/how-to-persist-permission-in-android-api-19-kitkat) related question and the suggested answers - hopefully this gives you some ideas as well.

Comment: I appreciate you sharing this related question. However, I was able to load a bitmap with persistent permissions like in this partial solution: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29588566). But, when I try to load a bitmap outside of the method onActivityResult, from saved content paths, in addition to it happening on a background process, it is then that I get the SecurityException. I'm guessing this is happening because the background process is a different user. Or the process ID being different is an issue. Perhaps...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my own problem. If you look at my code you can see that I used intent.getData(). Then I persisted the permission with that uri. When I saved the uri for later use I decoded it. `Uri.decode(uri.toString()`.

Encoded Uri: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A32`
Decoded: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:32`

So, I instead used intent.getDataString(), then used Uri.parse() to create a Uri for the takePersistableUriPermission() method. Then I saved the initial data string from the intent in the database which keeps the encoded components.

Comment: The attention to getDataString() really needs to be called out because it is missing in so many Stack articles and omitted the detail on Android.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the necessary permission in your Manifest.
Please add :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is necessary if you want to make write operations.

Give it a try and let us know if this helps.

Comment: I added this permission and I still get a SecurityException.