# App crashes when uploading image to firebase storage - Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

As soon as I upload an image from a path on the phone my app craches. The user is also successfully authenticated into the app and i've imported all the sdk's needed. It could be that the sdk's verision is not the right one, because it's not the newest verision. I followed this video: https://youtu.be/86dkYGeXMaU

this is my code:

```
private fun UploadToFirebaseStorage(){

    if(PhotoUri == null) return

    Log.d("AuthMsgs", PhotoUri.toString())
    val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

    val ref = 
    FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/$filename")

    ref.putFile(PhotoUri!!)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("AuthMsgs", "Photo Succes: " + it.metadata?.path)
            }


}
```

heres the log cat message:

```
2018-11-04 11:29:39.040 20493-20493/com.David.DiveBuddy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.David.DiveBuddy, PID: 20493
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider from ProcessRecord{6385df5 20493:com.David.DiveBuddy/u0a340} (pid=20493, uid=10340) that is not exported from uid 10106
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:4263)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5475)
    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2267)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1515)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1129)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:982)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:835)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:789)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.David.DiveBuddy.LoginReg.UploadToFirebaseStorage(Login_reg.kt:212)
    at com.David.DiveBuddy.LoginReg.access$UploadToFirebaseStorage(Login_reg.kt:31)
    at com.David.DiveBuddy.LoginReg$registerUser$1.onComplete(Login_reg.kt:153)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21082735/793943

Comment: At which line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied : opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.MediaContentProvider that is not exported from uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438537/permission-denied-opening-provider-com-google-android-apps-photos-contentprovi)

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to add the `GOOGLE_PHOTOS` permission to your `Manifest`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.apps.photos.permission.GOOGLE_PHOTOS"/>
```

Comment: "It didn't work." can be a lot of things. Please give some more information. Does it compile? Do you get another error?

Comment: I fixed it my self.

Comment: @DavidWenzel How did you fix this problem? I am running into it as well

Comment: @NdaJunior It was a long time ago. So I don't really remember. But I'll come back to you when/if I find out.

Comment: @NdaJunior Well, I think got around the problem by just not uploading any images to firebase.