# Firebase Continuing Uploads Across Process Does not work

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I been trying for hours and hours to work where the problem is, why image uploading does not resume after I relaunch the app..

Once I select the image and start uploading it sets the session Uri and local getData uri values to shared preferences:

```
 .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri sessionUri = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri();
                            if (sessionUri != null && uploading == null) {
                                editor.putString("upload",  sessionUri.toString()).commit();
                                editor.putString("local", selectedImageUri.toString()).commit();
                                editor.putString("ref", key).commit();
                            }

                            //calculating progress percentage
                            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") int bytesTransferred = (int) taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred();
                            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") int totalBytes = (int) taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                            int progress = (100 *  bytesTransferred) / totalBytes ;

                            pBar.setProgress(progress);
                            System.out.println("Uploading: " + progress);
                        }
                    });
```

Now If I were to kill the app, the values inside the shared reference are saved, but even the function is called for resuming the upload, nothing happens at all..

```
 uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(Uri.parse(uploadingLocal),
                        new StorageMetadata.Builder().build(), Uri.parse(uploading));
```

I have tried to use `uploadTask.pause();` or `uploadTask.notify();` but nothing.

I really have no idea what the problem is..

Answer (score 1):

I moved the function from the `onActivityResult()` to a separate `void` function.

Now when I called the function I just created I received `permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` error which pointed me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414352/how-to-persist-permission-in-android-api-19-kitkat#29588566) answer.. So basically my uri was the one causing the problem. Once relaunched app using modified intent, the uploading resumed.