# Giving equal priority to three different applications

Tags: java, c, performance, ubuntu, hard-drive

I have three applications running on a beefy machine at the same time (32GB memory) and 32 CPUs. The three applications have to run in parallel. Two of these applications are C applications and they are IO intensive (they are constantly writing a large amount of data to the disk). The third application is a java application which basically reads the files written by the first two applications and write different files. I can run each application smoothly without problems but when I try to run the three together, it seems that CPU% usage of the first applications are high and the CPU% usage for the third application shows as 0%. I am using Ubuntu linux. I am trying to give equal process priority to these applications. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: By default they have the same niceness (e.g. priority). How are you safely accessing the file for reading while some other file is writing to it?

Comment: On a side note, writing to files isn't a very good inter-process communication (IPC) mechanism. There are probably much better solutions to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Wait, if they are I/O-bound, why do you care about how much CPU time they consume? Shouldn't you be more concerned about whether you're utilizing the (limited) I/O bandwidth efficiently?

Comment: I produce sequential files, sample0, sample1, and so on....I dont access sample(i) until sample(i+2) exists

Comment: @NPE Yes, I want to distribute the IO efficiently among them but it seems the processor is not serving the third application at all, even for the non IO part

Comment: maybe this is an obvious question, but: are you falling behind? are the files being created faster than you can process them? (is it possible that the java app is just finishing faster?)

Comment: @JVMATL I have investigated this issue. The JAVA app stops completely when the other two applications are running. When I pause the other two applications (which I can do), the Java app finishes so fast. So the java app performance individually is more than good!

Comment: When I say "stops", I mean it is not being scheduled to run by the processor

Comment: Does you Java app requires a lock to be obtained to proceed?

Comment: Kinda sounds like your logic for not accessing sample(i) until sample(i+2) exists has a problem. Can you insert trace statements there to see if that is where the Java app is stuck?

Comment: Have you considered manually tweaking their performance using the "nice" command?  Perhaps you can slow down the first apps a bit. This is a hack, of course, but sometimes hacks work well enough.

Comment: @PM77-1 No, there are no locks whatsoever. I only wait for the existance of a file to proceed but I am sure this is not the problem.

Comment: @Ewald Yes, I inserted some trace outputting and the app doesnt even reach there which assures me that the CPU doesnt schedule the java app at all when the other two apps are running

Comment: @Keeto The file will exist for some time until all the bytes are written, unless you're writing in a temp folder and moving the "complete" file into the monitored directory. Are you?

Comment: It sounds like the problems is how your apps are scheduled by the OS, meaning, they don't work as you think they do. Some debugging should show what the problem is

Comment: I don't think this is a starvation issue; I think ewald might be onto something; the Java app would not get scheduled to run if the app were stuck in a blocking call - can you show code around where your Java app is waiting for something to do?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I only access sample(i) if sample(i+2) exists. It doesnt matter if sample(i+2) is not complete because sample(i+2) does not start until after sample(i) is complete

Comment: @keeto - here's where we are coming from: Linux does NOT just 'stop' a process because other processes are running. It may sometimes schedule things inefficiently, you may have a resource starvation problem that makes things move slowly, but it is extremely unlikely that the OS is stopping your Java app outright; you say you have traced the java app: what does your trace show? where does it get stuck? Can you make it happen in a debugger?

Comment: @JVMATL I agree with you and thats why I dont understand where the problem is coming from. My guess is that it is a disk starvation problem. The three apps access the disk heavily but the distribution is totally biased to the first two apps

Comment: So the $20,000 question is: where is your Java app's point of execution when you see it not executing for lengthy periods of time? If your theory of disk starvation is correct, then it should always be paused waiting for disk I/O.

Comment: Are you running some of the apps in the foreground, some in the background, all in the background, or what?

Comment: Suggestion: when I run out of clever ideas, I resort to brute force :) Copy your source code off (or check it into source control) and start removing code from your java app. Strip it down, down, down until it's nothing but a loop waiting for the next file to show up and then print a message saying "reading file X" -- do this step by step to get the smallest java program you can that still locks up. In doing this, you will either solve the problem, or have a nice, small bit of code to post so others can look at it and puzzle out where it's getting stuck.

Comment: @RonBurk I am running each app in a different terminal

Comment: @JVMATL Thanks. I will probably do that

Comment: Might I humbly suggest http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/cpulimit.1.html as a tool for limiting the CPU usage of the first apps?  Make sure that each app is allowed only 1 core, that way the Java app should get a core all of its own.

Comment: @ewald cpulimit is a good tool to know about, but he's running on a 32-core beast! Surely at least one of those cores has some spare time while the others are crunching away. (side note: I want one of those!)

Comment: @JVMATL - As envious as I am, I'm also curious to know how a 32-core machine can be showing this behaviour. The idea is to try and narrow it down a bit - sort of like a debug step. If it works, give each app 8 cores and have some spares left for other things :)

Comment: If the CPU usage is high they are not I/O bound. Examine your assumptions.

Comment: @EJP He never said they were I/O bound, only that they were I/O intensive.

Comment: Of course, I can easily construct an I/O bound situation with high CPU usage just by starting with lots of I/O and adding on more and more CPU activity between I/Os.

Comment: So, we still don't know if your Java app stops completely or just runs very, very slowly. It's also not precisely clear how your Java app waits for data--are you spinning in a loop calling File.exists()? I see the claim that this can produce "400MB of garbage per second": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321180/how-expensive-is-file-exists-in-java

Comment: @RonBurk It runs very very slowly. I actually tried a different app that just reads a 400MB file and it is taking forever

Comment: It seems my linux disk scheduler is set to "deadline". I am thinking of changing the scheduler to "cfq" which is supposedly fair

Comment: OK My Linux IO scheduler was the problem. Thank you for all your help guys.

Comment: Came this close to asking you to cat the scheduler, thought "Naw, what are the odds?" :-)

Comment: @ChrisHayes 'Constantly writing a large amount of data to the disk' sounds I/O bound to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I will answer my question in case someone comes across the same issue. My problem is I had an unfair disk scheduler. For Linux, there are many types of IO schedulers (deadline, cfq, noop). CFQ is a fair scheduler and it is the default in many linux distributions...except mine I guess! I changed the scheduler to CFQ and now it is working fine.
You can check your current scheduler using the command

```
 cat /sys/block/{device name}/queue/scheduler
```

You can set your IO scheduler using the command

```
 echo cfq > /sys/block/{device name}/queue/scheduler
```